# Merging json text into single dto

Tags: servicestack

is there a mechanism in servicestack.text to merge two json strings into a single dto?

The use case is merging complex settings from multiple sources into a single settings file

i.e.

{ "blah": { "params": { "default": "bar", "misc": "0", } } }

and

{ "blah": { "params": { "value": "val", "misc": "1", } } }

becomes

{ "blah": { "params": { "default": "bar", "value": "val", "misc": "1", } } }

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful of the trailing comma's as it's not valid JSON. But you can use the dynamic API of [ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to do this:

```
var json1 = "{\"blah\":{\"params\":{\"default\":\"bar\", \"misc\": \"0\" } } }";
var json2 = "{\"blah\":{\"params\":{\"value\":\"val\", \"misc\": \"1\" } } }";

var jsonObj = JsonObject.Parse(json1);
var jsonParams =jsonObj.Object("blah").Object("params");

foreach (var entry in JsonObject.Parse(json2).Object("blah").Object("params"))
{
    jsonParams[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
}

var to = new { blah = new { @params = jsonParams } };

to.ToJson().Print();
```

Which will output:

```
{"blah":{"params":{"default":"bar","misc":"1","value":"val"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't ever going to use JsonArrays, solution above could be written in recursive way:

```
public static JsonObject Merge(JsonObject @this, JsonObject that) {
  foreach (var entry in that) {
    var exists = @this.ContainsKey (entry.Key);
    if (exists) {
      var otherThis = JsonObject.Parse(@this.GetUnescaped (entry.Key));
      var otherThat = JsonObject.Parse(that.GetUnescaped (entry.Key));
      @this [entry.Key] = Merge (otherThis, otherThat).ToJson ();
    } else {
      @this [entry.Key] = entry.Value;
    }
  }
  return @this;
}
```